# JBoss server error

Tags: java, jboss

when i start server error occur

```
DEPLOYMENTS IN ERROR:
  Deployment "interface org.jboss.ejb3.timerservice.spi.TimerServiceFactory" is in error due to the following reason(s): Instantiated
  Deployment "jboss:service=KeyGeneratorFactory,type=HiLo" is in error due to the following reason(s): java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
  Deployment "persistence.unit:unitName=jboss-ejb3-timerservice-mk2.jar#timerdb" is in error due to the following reason(s): org.hibernate.HibernateException: 'hibernate.dialect' must be set when no Connection available, **ERROR**
at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.deployers.DeployersImpl.checkComplete(DeployersImpl.java:1228) [:2.2.2.GA]
at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.main.MainDeployerImpl.checkComplete(MainDeployerImpl.java:905) [:2.2.2.GA]
at org.jboss.system.server.profileservice.deployers.MainDeployerPlugin.checkComplete(MainDeployerPlugin.java:87) [:6.1.0.Final]
at org.jboss.profileservice.deployment.ProfileDeployerPluginRegistry.checkAllComplete(ProfileDeployerPluginRegistry.java:107) [:0.2.2]
at org.jboss.system.server.profileservice.bootstrap.BasicProfileServiceBootstrap.start(BasicProfileServiceBootstrap.java:135) [:6.1.0.Final]
at org.jboss.system.server.profileservice.bootstrap.BasicProfileServiceBootstrap.start(BasicProfileServiceBootstrap.java:56) [:6.1.0.Final]
at org.jboss.bootstrap.impl.base.server.AbstractServer.startBootstraps(AbstractServer.java:827) [jboss-bootstrap-impl-base.jar:2.1.0-alpha-6]
at org.jboss.bootstrap.impl.base.server.AbstractServer$StartServerTask.run(AbstractServer.java:417) [jboss-bootstrap-impl-base.jar:2.1.0-alpha-6]
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) [:1.8.0_31]`
```

Answer (score 0):

You have an application deployed that uses `hibernate`. As the error message sayes `org.hibernate.HibernateException: 'hibernate.dialect' must be set when no Connection available` you have to define a hibernate dialect.

Comment: More likely he needs to fix his connection to the database.